# How to join a one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to join a few tables together in Entity Framework. One of the relationships of the table is a One-To-Many relationship.

E.g. The object Person has a list of the object DATA, but when I include the table in entity framework, it only returns single item of DATA in my select clause.

The query looks like this:

```
                from persoon in PagedView.Context.PERSOON
                join verhuring in PagedView.Context.VERHURINGEN
                    .Where(
                        x => x.DatumGeldigTot == null || x.DatumGeldigTot >= OverzichtPersonenSearch.ReferentieDatum)
                on persoon.ComputerNr equals verhuring.PersoonsID into a
                from verhuring in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join eenheid in PagedView.Context.EENHEID
                on verhuring.Eenheid equals eenheid.ComputerNr into b
                from eenheid in b.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join data in PagedView.Context.DATA
                on persoon.ComputerNr equals data.COMPUTERNR into c
                from data in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new PersoonDto
                {
                    ComputerNr = persoon.ComputerNr,
                    EIGENREF = persoon.EIGENREF,
                    NAAM = persoon.NAAM,
                    ADRES = persoon.ADRES,
                    LANDCODE = persoon.LANDCODE,
                    POSTNR = persoon.POSTNR,
                    TELEFOON = persoon.TELEFOON,
                    EMAIL = persoon.EMAIL,
                    RIJKSREGISTER = persoon.RIJKSREGISTER,
                    SOORT_PERSOON = persoon.SOORT_PERSOON,
                    GESLACHT = persoon.GESLACHT,
                    DATUM = persoon.DATUM,
                    FAMILIENAAM = persoon.FAMILIENAAM,
                    VOORNAAM = persoon.VOORNAAM,
                    STRAAT = persoon.STRAAT,
                    NR = persoon.NR,
                    BUSNR = persoon.BUSNR,
                    Website = persoon.Website,
                    IsActief = persoon.IsActief,
                    Verhuringen = persoon.Verhuringen,
                    POSTNRS = persoon.POSTNRS,
                    BANKREKENING_IBAN = persoon.BANKREKENING_IBAN,
                    GEBOORTELAND = persoon.GEBOORTELAND,
                    GEBOORTEPLAATS = persoon.GEBOORTEPLAATS,
                    GEBOORTEDATUM = persoon.GEBOORTEDATUM,
                    BANKREKENINGOGM = persoon.BANKREKENINGOGM,
                    Nationaliteit = persoon.Nationaliteit,
                    DUBIEUZEHUURDER = persoon.DUBIEUZEHUURDER,
                    BEROEP = persoon.BEROEP,
                    Een = eenheid,
                    DATA = data // HERE IT FAILS, BECAUSE DATA IS OF TYPE ICOLLECTION<DATA> WHILE data IS A SINGLE OBJECT
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have converted a group-join into a left-join by unpacking the group.  GroupJoin returns the collection you want.

```
join data in PagedView.Context.DATA
on persoon.ComputerNr equals data.COMPUTERNR into c
//from data in c.DefaultIfEmpty()  //remove this line
...
DATA = c.ToList()
```